# Redirecting Tomcat requests to another host

Tags: tomcat, redirect

How is it possible to redirect requests Tomcat 5.5 receives with certain URL match to another Tomcat instance on another host, like I could do on an Apache host with rewrite rules?

Example:
I'd like to redirect all requests on `http://example.com:8080/xmpl` to `http://example.org:8080/xmpl` (with full path and GET parameters), but leave `http://example.com:8080/regular` for Tomcat at example.com on port 8080.
Here example.com and example.org are completely different hosts.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, we used a placeholder webapp with URL Rewrite Filter, http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ and the filter configuration from Erik Isaksson. This spared us from rebooting the server, which was quite important for the specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Place Apache in front of your Tomcat and use mod_jk to talk to your tomcat. You can then use all the power and features of Apache, as Tomcat really doesn't have any that you don't program yourself.